# How would I be able to make this Codepen project my website's background?

Tags: javascript, html, background

Sorry for the stupid question, but I was wondering how I would be able to make this javascript my website's background. Relatively new to JavaScript and am not quite sure how I would be able to implement it as the background.

LINK TO THE CODEPEN:

```
'''https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/JjdZKEa'''
```

Comment: haha, nice to see it here :), you can find more similar things on my telegram channel :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Disclaimer

First of - don't even think about trying to understand everything which is going in there. As a beginner you should really work your way up and at some point inventing your own fancy projects.

#### Implementation

HTML

```
<head>
    <!-- Other stuff -->
    <script defer src="https://raw.githack.com/strangerintheq/ShaderToy/master/ShaderToy.js"></script>
    <script defer src="shader.js"></script>
    <!-- Other scripts of yours -->
</head>
```

You are basically adding two scripts. The first one from a website the second one to one you have to copy yourself (that is the one you could see in the Codepen JS section).

JS

```
// filename: "shader.js"

// https://thelig.ht/chladni/

let uf = {xy: '2f'};

addEventListener('mousemove', e => uf.xy([e.x/innerWidth,e.y/innerHeight]))

new ShaderToy(`void main(void) {

const float PI = 3.14159265;
vec2 p = (2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy - resolution.xy) / resolution.y;

vec4 s1 = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0);
vec4 s2 = vec4(-4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.6);

float tx = sin(time)*0.1; 
float ty = cos(time)*0.1; 

float a = mix(s1.x, s2.x, xy.x+tx);
float b = mix(s1.y, s2.y, xy.x+tx);
float n = mix(s1.z, s2.z, xy.y+ty);
float m = mix(s1.w, s2.w, xy.y+ty);

float max_amp = abs(a) + abs(b);
float amp = a * sin(PI*n*p.x) * sin(PI*m*p.y) + b * sin(PI*m*p.x) * sin(PI*n*p.y);
float col = 1.0 - smoothstep(abs(amp), 0.0, 0.1);
gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(col), 1.0);

}`, {uniforms:uf}).fullscreen().loop();
```

I didn't bother to check what is going on there. If you are interested maybe you like to look up some tutorials about shaders.

CSS

```
canvas {
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Add this either in an external stylesheet or in your head section.
The Script works by creating a canvas on your page. This CSS moves it behind every element on your page (`z-index: -1`), makes it immovable (`position: fixed`) and starting at the very top edge of your window (`top: 0`).

Comment: So I was able to add the scripts to the site, but I'm not too sure on how to store it in a canvas. Without having a canvas the script still shows up fullscreen and everything, but it covers everything else on the site. EDIT: Nevermind, I think it automatically creates a canvas.

Comment: The two scripts will take care of that - **you don't add the canvas**. Have you tried adding the CSS styles? If you got the script running this should make it "the background" of your page.

Comment: Yeah I have it as the background. The problem now is that I'm fading in a viewport over the background and I'm not sure how to keep the background when the viewport fades in. If you could check out the site (https://rubyredsound.com) and help me out with fading it in with the viewport that would be awesome but don't worry about it if you can't haha I'm gonna keep messing with it. Just need to get the canvas into my viewport div.

Comment: On the page I can't see anything and there is no canvas element loaded so I believe sth went wrong executing the scripts. Make sure they load in the same order I have them in the HTML snippet.

Comment: Anyhow if you say it works for you I guess you want to fiddle around with the `opacity` CSS value to make it go from transparent to fully visible.

Comment: I haven't updated the site yet so thats why it isnt there, but currently, it creates the canvas in the body. I think that I would have to change the javascript or something in order to append it to my class named "viewport" instead of in the body

Comment: You can do that. If you past the script src in the url of your browser it should display the raw JS file. I believe if you change line 5 (`!config.target && document.body.append(c);`) to `!config.target && "yourViewport".append(c);` you should get what you need?
If there are any issues whit that i'd recommend editing the original question or creating a new one - good luck :)